# jQuery UI; know the child# when dragging sortable items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parent-child

I have sortable list that grows based on custom user input through an Add-button.
The top and bottom item in the list are the max. and min. values and I need to know when they are dragged and where to. To figure this out I looked into the "event" and "ui" objects in the Safari Inspector to find out if those objects contain which index (number) of child the grabbed up HTML-Object is.

Here's my code:

```
// Define the sorting settings/rules of the dsList (items list)
$('#dsList').sortable({
    handle: '.handle',
    cursor: 'move',
    axis: 'y',
    opacity: 0.7,
    scroll: true,
    start: function(event, ui) {

    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        // Find out if the first or last item was dragged
        var firstDragged = false;
        var lastDragged = false;

        if ($(ui.item[0]).find('.firstItem').val() != undefined) {
            firstDragged = true;
        }

        if ($(ui.item[0]).find('.lastItem').val() != undefined) {
            lastDragged = true;
        }

        // Calculate the list values
        var itemsCount = $('#dsList').children().length;
        //console.log(itemsCount);

        // Check if the first item dragged below the last
        console.log(ui);


        // Update list settings
        updateListSettings();

        // Refresh the list
        updateList();
    }
});
```

The problem here is "this" represents the parent (#dsList) and I can't find the child-number of the object I'm dragging. I can calculate how much pixels the element has been moved and then calculate that times it's height, but I don't like that idea in means of scalability in the future.

Any idea how I can get the childCount of the dragged element based on it's parent (#dsList)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a not-so-pretty fix, but it at least works:

```
    update: function(event, ui) {
        // Calculate the list values
        var itemsCount = $('#dsList').children().length;

        // Refresh the list to be able to search for the change
        $(this).sortable('refreshPositions');

        // Check if the first item dragged below the last
        if ($('#dsList .dsListItem:nth-last-child(1) .firstItem').attr('autocomplete') == 'off') {
            console.log('first item is moved beyond last');
        }

        // Check if the last item dragged above the first
        if ($('#dsList .dsListItem:nth-child(1) .lastItem').attr('autocomplete') == 'off') {
            console.log('last item is moved above first');
        }

        // Update list settings
        updateListSettings();

        // Refresh the list
        updateList();
    }
```

Somehow the returned object is not fully empty, so I had to see if there was an object inside it.
This way it can check if the the .firstItem ended up at the end of the heap and vice versa.

```
$(this).sortable('refreshPositions');
```

.. is a must! Or the object will be mashed-up, even using the update call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find out if a dragged object is first or last within its list of siblings.
If that assumption is correct, then I'd suggest using:

```
if (ui.item.prevAll().length == 0) {
    firstDragged = true;
}

if (ui.item.nextAll().length == 0) {
    lastDragged = true;
}
```

Update on Feb. 12th:
Before giving up, I've tried a different approach in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/LqZPU/4/) and it works for me:

```
$( "#dslist" ).sortable({
    opacity: 0.7
    ,revert:600
    ,delay:100
    ,scroll: true
    ,start: function( event, ui ) {
        var $items = $(this).children(
            ":not(.ui-sortable-helper,.ui-sortable-placeholder)"
        );
        $(this).data("firstDragged", ui.item.is( $items.first() ));
        $(this).data("lastDragged", ui.item.is( $items.last() ));
    }
    ,update: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log("firstDragged: " + $(this).data("firstDragged"));
        console.log("lastDragged: " + $(this).data("lastDragged"));
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Sadly that does not work, even not with a refresh call of the Sortable class :(

Comment: @Allendar, I've edited the answer with a different approach. Includes link to jsfiddle.